# Java Criteria API join self referencing entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, criteria, criteria-api

I'm trying to do a nested join on a self referencing entity, please bear with me, it will make sense :)

**Thing.java**

```
class Thing {
  Integer something;
  Person owner;
}
```

**Person.java**

```
class Person {
  String name;
  Person parent; 
}
```

*Note: A Person with parent=null means that they are a parent, and cannot have a parent. It's an alien world! :P*

**Query:**

```
Root<Thing> root = query.from(Thing.class);

Join<Thing, Person> ownerJoin = root.join(Thing_.owner);
Join<Person, Person> parentJoin = ownerJoin.join(Person_.parent);

Path<String> ownerNameField = ownerJoin.get(Person_.name);
Path<String> parentNameField = parentJoin.get(Person_.name);

return cb.or(cb.equal(ownerNameField, "John"), cb.equal(parentNameField, "John"));
```

So basically, I'm trying to find "Things" that either belong to me, or that I'm the parent of the Person who owns that "Thing".

The SQL statement I'm trying to generate is supposed to look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Thing t 
WHERE 
    t.something = 1 
    AND (t.owner.name = "John" OR t.owner.parent.name = "John")
```

Now the problem is that with this criteria it's only giving me the results of *t.owner.parent.name = "John"*

Comment: Do the owners named John have a parent? What is the SQL that is generated?

Comment: A Person with parent=null means that they are a parent, and cannot have a parent. It's an alien world haha

Comment: t.owner.parent.name = 'John' creates an inner join. So this query will never return a thinh linked to a parentless owner. You need a left join.